# Rationals of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are primes in $[a,b]$

Tags: number-theory, real-analysis, analysis, prime-numbers

Consider the closed interval $[0,1]$, there is $\frac{2}{3} \in [0,1]$ where $p=2$ and $q=3$. Similarly consider $[2,3]$, one can have $\frac{5}{2} \in [2,3]$ where $p=5$ and $q=2$. Does every interval of the form $[a,b]$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ contain a rational of this kind. If yes, how can we prove it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried using the Prime Number Theorem in the form $p_n \sim n \log n$?

Comment: You can read [Quotients of Primes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324814?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by David Hobby and D. M. Silberger.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Roughly speaking this asks whether the quotients of two primes
are dense in the positive reals. The answer is yes.

Let $0 < a < b$ and let $q$ be a prime.
Then there will a a prime $p$ with $a < p/q\le b$ if and only if
$\pi(bq) > \pi(aq)$ where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function.
But by the prime number theorem, as $q\to\infty$,
$$\frac{\pi(bq)}{\pi(aq)}\sim\frac{b\log(aq)}{a\log(bq)}
=\frac{b(\log q+\log a)}{a(\log q+\log b)}\sim\frac ba>1.$$
For all large enough $q$, $\pi(bq)/\pi(aq) > 1$ as required.

Comment: +1 -- although I wonder if we really need the prime number theorem here

Comment: Right, I was getting at something similar in my comment above.  Recently I have been starting to wonder whether we should be giving hints rather than complete answers to questions like this.

Comment: I feel like you don't need the Prime Number Theorem for this.

Comment: So given a  and b , for  a sufficiently large prime q you can always  find a prime  p  between aq and bq. Right,  someone remind me, why was this problem rewarded with 50 points?

Comment: Not using the PNT to solve this question is not obvious, see my comments on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013414.