# Exercise I.1.6 from Tenenbaum's "Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory"

Tags: analytic-number-theory

So this question has been asked before, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19916/the-set-of-rational-numbers-of-the-form-p-p-where-p-and-p-are-prime-is-dense), but instead of how to go from part 4 to part 5, I am having a difficult time proving part 4:

> For each $\alpha > 0$ there exists a sequence of integers $\{n_1, n_2, \dots \}$, increasing in the weak sense, such that $p_{n_j} \sim \alpha j \qquad (j \to \infty)$.

How does it follow from the previous part?

Comment: A first step should be to figure out what the $n_j$ should look like.  Because $p_n\sim n\log n$, we need that the sequence satisfies $\alpha j \sim n_j \log n_j$.  Note that if $n_j \sim \alpha j/\log j$, then $\log n_j \sim \log \alpha +\log j -\log \log j \sim \log j$.  Is this precise enough?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $$n_j=\left[\frac{\alpha j}{\log j}\right].$$

Then $$p_{n_j}\sim n_j \log(n_j)\sim \frac{\alpha j}{\log j}\log\left(\frac{\alpha j}{\log j}\right)=\alpha j+\frac{\alpha j}{\log j}\log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\log j}\right)$$

$$=\alpha j+O\left(\frac{\alpha j\log \log j}{\log j}\right)\sim \alpha j.$$

Comment: +1 for the correct use of several signs $\sim$ and $=$ in the same sentence.