# Dense subsets of $R$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ two sequences of natural numbers such that, $a_n\to +\infty$ and $b_n\to +\infty$. Prove that: 
$$K=\{\pm\frac  {a_n}{b_m}:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

In consequence, prove that the quotients of two primes are dense in the positive reals.

I know that I can prove the second part like in: "[Rationals of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are primes in $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/rationals-of-the-form-fracpq-where-p-q-are-primes-in-a-b)", but I was wondering if I could prove without the prime number theorem.

Comment: It is not true. Let $a_n=10^n, b_n=10^n$, then $\frac{a_n}{b_m} = 10^{n-m}$, and so the corresponding $K$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Zero must be in the closure, of course.

Comment: I wonder what extra conditions might be imposed to imply the desired density. (Maybe another question could be put about that.)

Comment: Where did you get this problem (they are asking you to prove something that is not true)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. For example, take $a_n=b_n=2^n$. Then $K$ consists of $\pm$ all powers of $2$ to integer exponents, and that's certainly not dense.

Comment: @T.Bongers  $a_n/b_m=2^{n-m}$ is a power of $2$ for all $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Ah, yes. I misread it, sorry.