# Are fractions with prime numerator and denominator dense?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

So the question is in the title. And I mean dense in positive real numbers ofcourse. Somehow I cannot grasp if this is very trivial or not. The prime numbers aren't that dense, but are there enough of primes to make the fractions constructed from them dense?

Comment: See the following post on mathoverflow:


http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117191/using-quotient-of-prime-numbers-to-approximation-reals

Comment: You can read _[Quotients of Primes](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324814)_ by David Hobby and D. M. Silberger.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066. (Note: the above paper does use the prime number theorem as well).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can establish this with the prime number theorem, which can essentially be seen to state that, where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p_n}{n\log(n)}=1.$$
Using this, suppose that we wish to show that there is a fraction with prime numerator and denominator in the interval $\left(\frac{1}kx,kx\right)$ for $k>1$. Choose some $k-1>\varepsilon>0$ which we will later use for some wiggle-room. Let $N$ be such that, for all $n>N$ we have
$$\left(\frac{p_n}{n\log(n)}\right)^2\in\left(\frac{1+\varepsilon}k,\frac{k}{1+\varepsilon}\right)$$
which is possible due to the limit and since squaring is continuous and the right interval is open and contains $1$. Then, we merely need to find a pair $n_1$ and $n_2$ greater than $N$ satisfying
$$\frac{n_1\log(n_1)}{n_2\log(n_2)}\in\left(\frac{x}{1+\varepsilon},x(1+\varepsilon)\right)$$
which should be easy enough to find given the identity that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x k \log(x k)}{k \log(k)}=x$$
meaning we can choose $n_1$ and $n_2$ to have ratio near $x$, and so long as they are sufficiently large, this means that the appropriate ratio of $n\log(n)$ too will be near $x$. Then we will have that the ratio of $\frac{p_{n_1}}{p_{n_2}}$ differs from $\frac{n_1\log(n_1)}{n_2\log(n_2)}$ by a factor in $\left(\frac{1+\varepsilon}k,\frac{k}{1+\varepsilon}\right)$, and hence the ratio of the two primes would be in $\left(\frac{1}kx,kx\right)$, as desired. This works on any interval, hence the fractions with prime terms are dense.