# Result related to asymptotics.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I am studying number theory and I want to know if the following statement is true:

If $f(x)\sim g(x)$ and $g(x)>a$ for all $x\geq x_0$ then $\exists x_1$ such that $f(x)>a$ for all $x\geq x_1$.

Can someone give me a proof or counterexample.

Actually I want a justification for the step $\dfrac{\pi(bq)}{\pi(aq)}\sim \dfrac{b}{a}>1\implies\pi(bq)>\pi(aq),$ in the answer to the following question: [Rationals of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are primes in $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/rationals-of-the-form-fracpq-where-p-q-are-primes-in-a-b)

Comment: As a somewhat pedantic counterexample, $f(x)=a,g(x)=a+h(x)$ where $h>0,h \to 0$. This only contradicts the idea that $f$ inherits a *strict* inequality.

Comment: Yeah what you want is trivial. It is the same idea as the ratio test; wait for the ratio to exceed $\frac{\frac{b}{a}+1}{2}$ and then the numerator is greater than the denominator.